# How to fix this expression is not assignable error?

Tags: c, c-strings

I need to do this method where I have a string and it should all be vowels or else the method will return false, but I am getting this expression assignable error, I am just a beginner in coding, could someone please help me? Thanks!

```
int verify_vowel(char *string, char elem, int length){
    if(string != NULL){
        value= TRUE;
        for (i=0; i<length && value == TRUE; i++) {
            if(string[i] == elem){
                int is_vowel(char element);
                value = TRUE;
            }else{
                value= FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```
int is_vowel(char element){
    int j;
    int value1;
    int length;
    char string2[LENGTH];
    value1= TRUE;
    for(j=0; j<length && value1== TRUE; j++){
        if(string2[j]= 'a' && string2[j]= 'e' && string2[j]='i' && string2[j]='o' && string2[j]= 'u'){ //im getting the error here
            value1= TRUE;
        } else{
            value1= FALSE;
        }
    }
    int main(){
    char string[]= "aeiuodsf";
    int ret;
    ret= is_vowel(string);
    printf("Result: %d\n",ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `value` defined? How is `TRUE/FALSE` defined? Also please post the complete error message and elaborate where in the code it appears (usually the compiler says in which line it has problems)

Comment: Okay i now saw the comment your problem is `(string2[j]= 'a'..` this is an assignement not a comparison you should use `==`. Also the expression will always be false because the same character cant be several characters at once you may use `||` logical or or `strcmp()`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately some parts are missing: Where do you get this error message? Where is `value` defined? What is the purpose of declaring `is_vowel` inside `verify_vowel`? Please read [How To ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `ret= is_vowel(string);`The function takes a `char` but you provide a `char *`

Comment: Note that `verify_vowel()` is not used. There is a great deal wrong with the code. For example in `is_vowel()` the variable `char string2[LENGTH];` is not initialised, but is checked. Also, the iteration does not terminate on failure but returns the state of the final character, regardless of what else was found. But the function is incomplete and does not return a value anyway.

Comment: regarding: `char string2[LENGTH];
    for(j=0; j<length ...
        if(string2[j]= 'a' && string2[j]= 'e' && string2[j]='i' && string2[j]='o' && string2[j]= 'u')`  The array: `string2]` is not initialized so contains what every trash was on the stack at its' location.  You compiler should have told you about using an uninitialized variable

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is used for assignment, while `==` is used for comparison (you can use `strcmp` too if you want). In this case, you are assigning instead of comparing, that's why you get the error. Moreover, `verify_vowel` is never used. You can do it this way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_vowel(char *element, int length){
    for(int j=0; j<length; j++){
        if(!(element[j]== 'a' || element[j]== 'e' || 
            element[j]== 'i' || element[j]== 'o' || 
            element[j]== 'u')){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char *string= "aeifou";
    int ret;
    ret= is_vowel(string,strlen(string));
    printf("Result: %d\n",ret);
    return 0;
}
```